# phonegap build generic push plugin - no valid aps-environment

Tags: ios, cordova, push-notification

im trying to use the generic push for my app. it works on android but on ios i get the error msg: no valid aps-environment

1. i have added support to push notifications in apple provisioning
   profile
2. i created and downloaded the provisioning profile after enabling the push
3. i have `<key>aps-environment</key>` in mobileprovision
4. i have installed the mobile provision and app on my phone
5. i have checked and tested every solution

my config.xml

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <widget xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
        id        = "---.-------.-----"
        versionCode="10" 
        version   = "1.1.0">

    <!-- versionCode is optional and Android only -->

    <name>PhoneGap push Example</name>

    <description>
        An example for phonegap build docs. 
    </description>

   <author href="http://-----------" email="---------------">------</author>
<access origin="*" />

<!--DEVICE FEATURES ACCESS--> 
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/camera"/>
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/file"/>
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/geolocation"/>
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/media"/>
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/network"/>
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/notification"/>

<gap:plugin name="GenericPush" /> <!-- latest release -->
</widget>
```

my js

```
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jquery_1.5.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="PushNotification.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var pushNotification;         
        function onDeviceReady() {
            $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>deviceready event received</li>');

            pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
            if (device.platform == 'android' || device.platform == 'Android') {
                pushNotification.register(successHandler, errorHandler, {"senderID":"661780372179","ecb":"onNotificationGCM"});
            } else {
                pushNotification.register(tokenHandler, errorHandler, {"badge":"true","sound":"true","alert":"true","ecb":"onNotificationAPN"});
            }
        }

        // handle APNS notifications for iOS
        function onNotificationAPN(event) {
            if (event.alert) {
                $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>push-notification: ' + event.alert + '</li>');
                navigator.notification.alert(event.alert);
            }

            if (event.sound) {
                var snd = new Media(event.sound);
                snd.play();
            }

            if (event.badge) {
                pushNotification.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(successHandler, event.badge);
            }
        }

        // handle GCM notifications for Android
        function onNotificationGCM(e) {
            $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>EVENT -> RECEIVED:' + e.event + '</li>');

            switch( e.event )
            {
                case 'registered':
                if ( e.regid.length > 0 )
                {
                    $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>REGISTERED -> REGID:' + e.regid + "</li>");
                    // Your GCM push server needs to know the regID before it can push to this device
                    // here is where you might want to send it the regID for later use.
                    console.log("regID = " + regID);
                }
                break;

                case 'message':
                $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>MESSAGE -> MSG: ' + e.message + '</li>');
                $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>MESSAGE -> MSGCNT: ' + e.msgcnt + '</li>');
                break;

                case 'error':
                $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>ERROR -> MSG:' + e.msg + '</li>');
                break;

                default:
                $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>EVENT -> Unknown, an event was received and we do not know what it is</li>');
                break;
            }
        }

        function tokenHandler (result) {
            $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>token: '+ result +'</li>');
            // Your iOS push server needs to know the token before it can push to this device
            // here is where you might want to send it the token for later use.
        }

        function successHandler (result) {
            $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>success:'+ result +'</li>');
        }

        function errorHandler (error) {
            $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>error:'+ error +'</li>');
        }

        document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, true);

     </script>

    <div id="app-status-div">
        <ul id="app-status-ul">
            <li>Cordova PushNotification Plugin Demo</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: same problem here. I will try to skip the development certificates and use the production ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after long research and trial and error. i found out that i need to use:
on IOS (adhoc provision profile) and on push server(production aps cert and key)

Answer (score 1):

According to the Phonegap Build community forums, you need to use a distribution provision certificate for the APS registration to work : http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/ios_problem_with_push_notification_plugin_for_phonegap_build

Some people have succeeded after switching to production certificates.
However, I have the same problem and still cannot get it working with production certificates.